# If $\left|z+\frac{2}{z}\right |=2$, then prove that max value of $|z|$ is $\sqrt 3 + 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solving the quadratic inequality

$$|z|\ge1+i$$ and $$|z|\le1-i$$

I don’t know how to solve further. Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Since moduli must be real, as it stands this problem has no solutions. I can't work out what it should read. Double-check every detail.

Comment: If the question is exactly as in the title then all you have to do is consider a real-valued variable, say $x$. No need to consider the modulus of a complex since the complex structure is totally washed away in the thesis of the question.

Comment: let $x=\vert z\vert$ your equation reads $x+1/x=2$ or $x^2-2x+1=0$ or $x=1$, so  $\vert z \vert=1 $ and there is a mistake in your question

Comment: @J.G. I am sorry, I had the wrong question. I checked it in another book (printing mistake). Corrected question is up there

Answer (score 1):

It should read $$|z|-\frac 2{|z|}=2$$
since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3 +1$ is $X^2-2X-2$.

Now with the correct question at hand, simply note that since every complex number appears inside a modulus, this question really is about non-negative real numbers. Solving the quadratic equation tells you what the possibilities are, and $\sqrt 3 +1$ is easily seen to be the largest (and also the only one that is non-negative).

Therefore $\sqrt 3+1$ is not simply the largest possible value of $|z|$, it is the *only* possible value.

Answer (score 0):

It should read $|z|-\frac{2}{|z|}=2$. If $t:=|z|$ , we get the equation $t^2-2t-2=0.$ This equation has the sulutions $t_{1/2}=1  \pm \sqrt{3}.$ Can you proceed ?

Edit: your questions has changed !

Comment: The question has been edited. I am very sorry for inconvenience caused.

Comment: Should I just close this and ask a new question?